# React Router NavLink not triggering history.listen() function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-ga

I am trying to implement Google Analytics using the `react-ga` library which needs to fire whenever the route changes. I have the following setup in App.js:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
...

const history = createBrowserHistory();
history.listen((location) => {
    console.log('ANALYTICS CODE GOES HERE', location);
});

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={...}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    ....
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

When I click on a `NavLink` throughout my app, the route changes and loads the appropriate component, but the `history.listen()` function never fires. However, if I use the browser's back/forward functionality it does fire.

```
<NavLink to="/account" activeClassName="active">ACCOUNT</NavLink>
```

**How do I listen to route changes triggered by a `NavLink`?**

Edit: further discussion taking place here: https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/122#issuecomment-316427527

Comment: I can't be sure but this sounds like the history isn't being passed down correctly. Which version of ReactRouter are you using? Also which `Router` are you importing?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [react-router `<Route />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) component as a wrapper for your tracking function - the route re-renders every time the location changes. For example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

ReactGA.initialize('UA-00000000-1')

const tracker = ({location}) => {
  // console.log('tracking', location.pathname)
  ReactGA.set({page: location.pathname})
  ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname)
  return null
}

const App = (props) => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route render={tracker} />
      ...
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```